# Woo commerce shop page - slider first on mobile - Woo Commerce and Woo Sliders

Tags: woocommerce, woothemes

I'm working on a wordpress site for a client and they have a dedicated plugin for ecommerce called woocommerce.

on a clients website that i'm changing, they want the website to be responsive. On their shop page on the left side there is a sidebar with ajax widgets for filtering products, which i cant seem to change the position of. I had to use CSS to move it to the left side, its origin was to the right. While on the right side is the product results. 
In mobile nothing works, divs are covering links and the filters are displaying off to the side and below the product results. 
what I want to do is display the filters first in mobile version, followed by the product results. is this possible? what should I change?

client website grittyrunner.jlbworks.com

child product archive file -

```
<?php

remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woocommerce_product_reviews_tab', 30);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_tab_panels', 'woocommerce_product_reviews_panel',   30);
/**
* The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a     post type archive.
*
* Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php
*
* @author WooThemes
* @package WooCommerce/Templates
* @version 2.0.0
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

get_header( 'shop' ); ?>

<?php
/**
 * woocommerce_before_main_content hook
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
 * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
?>

<?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>


    <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>


<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' ); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
         * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
    ?>

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
    ?>

<?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

    <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The link you posted doesn't work.

Comment: www.grittyrunner.jlbworks.net

Answer (score 0):

In the woocommerce folder there is a file called "archive-product.php", move the "woocommerce_sidebar" action to above the "woocommerce_before_main_content" action.

When the screen size is small then the side bar will display above the products.

It is recommenced to override the template and not just edit it in the plugin because those changes will be lost if the plugin is every updated.

So copy: `woocommerce/archive-product.php` to `yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php`

Comment: That didn't seem to change the order of the content when in smaller screen sizes or scaled down smaller. the sidebar is still below. i cut and pasted the sidebar action above the main content action in both archive-product files, the one i have in my woocommerce folder in my theme, and the actual archive-product file for woocommerce

Comment: Even when i take out woocommerce_sidebar do_action the sidebar still remains there!

Comment: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/  this link explains a bit about how the hooks are behaving but its still too much for me to understand completely